# Можно ли как-то узнать, обновил ли пользователь страницу?

Tags: php

Хочу сделать так, чтоб когда пользователь нажал перегрузить страницу, то его перенесло на главную страницу, а если нет, то и оставить на этой, можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Сессии в помощь.

Comment: Можно как то подробно?

Comment: можно ли как-то проверить или пользователь выключил свет в комнате? хочу что бы он со стула упал =)

Comment: Я бы на такой сайт больше никогда не зашел!

Answer (score 3):

ЯваСкрипт: события объекта window: onunload и для IE еще onbeforeunload. При рефреше наступают эти события. Если есть желание прервать укажи в этих событиях return false.
А если чтото другое то можно подумать)

Comment: В хроме это не будет работать. Кроме того эти же события наступают и при клике на ссылку.

Comment: document.onreadystatechange чудеснее работать будет. ИМХО)

Answer (score 1):

Прямого способа это сделать нет, можно заняться сессиями или куками, но это все довольно извращенно.Зато возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Запомнить последний запрос пользователя, в случае повторения запроса - страница обновлена.

Может так прокатит?

Answer (score 0):

Анализируйте реферер, например средствами javascript... Если он равен текущей странице, значит пользователь обновил страницу.